# Data Manipulation: Stemming from a inability to select lists

Tags: python

I am very new to python with no real prior programing knowledge. At my current job I am being asked to take data in the form of text from about 500+ files and plot them out. I understand the plotting to a degree, but I cannot seem to figure out how to manipulate the data in a way that it is easy to select specific sections. Currently this is what I have for opening a file:

```
fp=open("file")
for line in fp:
    words = line.strip().split()
    print words
```

The result is it gives me a list for each line of the file, but I can only access the last line made. Does any one know a way that would allow me to ***choose*** different variations of lists? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a list of lines from a file is as follows:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Now you can split those lines or do whatever you want with them:

```
lines = [line.split() for line in lines]
```

I'm not certain that answers your question -- let me know if you have something more specific in mind.

---

Since I don't understand *exactly* what you are asking, here are a few more examples of how you might process a text file. You can experiment with these in the interactive interpreter, which you can generally access just by typing 'python' at the command line.

```
>>> with open('a_text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
...     text = f.read()
... 
>>> text
'the first line of the text file\nthe second line -- broken by a symbol\nthe third line of the text file\nsome other data\n'
```

That's the raw, unprocessed text of the file. It's a string. Strings are immutable -- they can't be altered -- but they can be copied in part or in whole.

```
>>> text.splitlines()
['the first line of the text file', 'the second line -- broken by a symbol', 'the third line of the text file', 'some other data']
```

`splitlines` is a string method. `splitlines` splits the string wherever it finds a `\n` (newline) character; it then returns a list containing copies of the separate sections of the string.

```
>>> lines = text.splitlines()
```

Here I've just saved the above list of lines to a new variable name.

```
>>> lines[0]
'the first line of the text file'
```

Lists are accessed by indexing. Just provide an integer from `0` to `len(lines) - 1` and the corresponding line is returned.

```
>>> lines[2]
'the third line of the text file'
>>> lines[1]
'the second line -- broken by a symbol'
```

Now you can start to manipulate individual lines.

```
>>> lines[1].split('--')
['the second line ', ' broken by a symbol']
```

`split` is another string method. It's like `splitlines` but you can specify the character or string that you want to use as the demarcator.

```
>>> lines[1][4]
's'
```

You can also index the characters in a string.

```
>>> lines[1][4:10]
'second'
```

You can also "slice" a string. The result is a copy of characters 4 through 9. 10 is the stop value, so the 10th character isn't included in the slice. (You can slice lists too.)

```
>>> lines[1].index('broken')
19
```

If you want to find a substring within a string, one way is to use `index`. It returns the index at which the first occurrence of the substring appears. (It throws an error if the substring isn't in the string. If you don't want that, use `find`, which returns a -1 if the substring isn't in the string.)

```
>>> lines[1][19:]
'broken by a symbol'
```

Then you can use that to slice the string. If you don't provide a stop index, it just returns the remainder of the string.

```
>>> lines[1][:19]
'the second line -- '
```

If you don't provide a start index, it returns the beginning of the string and stops at the stop index.

```
>>> [line for line in text.splitlines() if 'line' in line]
['the first line of the text file', 'the second line -- broken by a symbol', 'the third line of the text file']
```

You can also use `in` -- it's a boolean operation that returns `True` if a substring is in a string. In this case, I've used a list comprehension to get only the lines that have `'line'` in them. (Note that the last line is missing from the list. It has been filtered.)

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: And I would suggest reading http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: This helps a lot! However, is there a way to select just a portion of the line?

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! I am not sure how to accept of upvote thhough, the website keeps saying that I don't have the points?